# Exclude IE8 for closure compilation

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm use Google Closure Compiler first time and after compilation some js code compiler gives error

```
JSC_TRAILING_COMMA: Parse error. IE8 (and below) will parse trailing commas in array and object literals incorrectly
```

But my code my code is meant to recent browsers.

Is there any option for exclude compilation for IE8?

Comment: So why it says IE8(and below)? it is working code

Comment: I was wrong. ES5 [allows a trailing comma in a object literal](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5). Anyway, the simplest fix is to *remove* any such trailing comma from such object literals for compatibility with ES3-only implementations (ie. IE8). (Older versions of FF accepted the then-invalid ES3 grammar productions.)

Comment: If the google closure compiler does not show you the line, then use jslint or jshint with your code it should show you a line like e.g. `{key: value, ... , keyN:valueN,}` when you remove the last `,` then you won't have the `JSC_TRAILING_COMMA` error anymore. This last `,` will (no matter if _compiled_  or not) produces an error in IE. ([Internet Explorer, Closure Compiler and Trailing Commas](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11823162/1960455))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to support older IE's you can set the language mode to "ECMASCRIPT5" or "ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT", and you will no longer receive this warning.

https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#I_get_a_"Trailing_comma_is_not_legal"_error._But_it_wo